# how to fix position of header view of listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using SwipListView ([github demo](https://github.com/huazhiyuan2008/SwipeListView)) in my application and I add the header view in it like this listView.addHeaderView(headerView);

I want to fix the position of this header , header should not scroll with listview. I search a lot on this but cant find any solution , I just see stickyListHeaders but thay user Framlayout

Comment: add a header above the listview in your xml layout. it wont scroll then

Comment: added the header above tha listview in xml if u use listview.addHeaderView() this is added in listview not in your view

Comment: @Hector and naveen: I know that solution, but actually I have to swapping the row in listView items with this header with animation like done in xe currency app , so my issue is if I use different view as a header then animation is not happen like xe currency

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use a layout on the top of the listview as header. So that when you scroll your listview, header sticks at its position.

```
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical">   <-----Main Parent View---->

   <RelativeLayout> 


 <----Fixed Header View------->


   </RelativeLayout>


   <ListView> 


<----scrollable list view----->


  </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: because I have done so many task with SwipeListView in my application and If I use StickyListHeaders or StickyScrollViewItems Demo on github then I have to do so many changes in it and I also have to implement that right side button of swipListView